# Issue with using 2 INNER JOINS within 1 mySQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query that is doing an `INNER JOIN` within a select query to insert records into the table. The issue is instead of using the WHERE clause and listing the 3 t2.device I would like to see, I need to do another INNER JOIN with a table called tbl_Full_List.

Both `tbl_Full_List and tbl1_device` have a column called device so instead of the WHERE clause I would like it to show only devices that match in both `tbl_Full_List and tbl1_device`

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_Table1 (place, device, description, quantity)
            (SELECT t1.place, t2.device, t2.description, Sum(t2.quantity) AS quantity
            FROM Device_Table AS t1
            INNER JOIN tbl1_device AS t2
            ON t1.rma = t2.rma
            WHERE t2.device IN ('PRT1030', 'PRT-23','PRT-20139')
            AND t1.date_made = Current_Date()
            GROUP BY t1.place, t2.device, t2.description ORDER BY place ASC, device ASC )
```

Comment: What is the `tbl_Full_List` table and how does it relate to your current query?

Comment: but we don't know how tbl1_device and full tbl_list_relate; so we can't do this.  But bascially just remove the in and put an inner join after your on to tbl_fulL_list and then add your on caluse showing how the two relate.

Comment: `tbl_Full_List` just has 1 column called device with a list of device names, those that match `tbl1_device` should show in the query results

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing how the two relate...  I'm assuming FL.ID is the PK of full list and we have a Foreign Key to tbl1_devcice called FL_ID

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_Table1 (place, device, description, quantity)
(SELECT t1.place, t2.device, t2.description, Sum(t2.quantity) AS quantity
 FROM Device_Table AS t1
 INNER JOIN tbl1_device AS t2
    ON t1.rma = t2.rma
 INNER JOIN tbl_Full_List FL
    ON FL.Device = t2.Device
 WHERE t1.date_made = Current_Date()
 GROUP BY t1.place, t2.device, t2.description ORDER BY place ASC, device ASC )
```

Comment: Why are you doing `INNER JOIN tbl_Full_List FL
    ON FL.ID = t2.FL_ID` if both have the column device? Why not INNER JOIN on the column device?

Comment: Good point that.  I didn't see that in the question initially.